# How to set BBR on GKE clusters?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

What is the best way to enable BBR on default for my clusters?
In this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-system-config), I didn't see an option for controlling the congestion control.

Answer (score 1):

Google BBR can only be enabled in Linux operating systems. By default the Linux servers uses Reno and CUBIC but the latest version kernels also includes the google BBR algorithms and can be enabled manually.

To enable it on CentOS 8 add below lines in /etc/sysctl.conf and issue command sysctl -p

net.core.default_qdisc = fq
net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = bbr

For more Linux distributions you can refer to this [link](https://supporthost.in/how-to-install-google-bbr/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe set it as part of your Deployment spec:

```yaml
spec:
  initContainers:
    - name: sysctl-buddy
      image: busybox:1.29
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
      command: ["/bin/sh"]
      args:
        - -c
        - sysctl -w net.core.default_qdisc=fq net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=bbr
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1m
          memory: 1Mi
```